# grails i18n error customization: various inconsistencies

Tags: grails

As an example, the default i18n message in message.properties for blank fields is:

```
default.blank.message=Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be blank
```

If one wants to customize this with a given class (e.g. user) and field (e.g. login), one does

```
user.login.blank=Your login name must be specified
```

with the ".message" suffix left-off.  This threw me off for a bit (as I had it in there and it didn't work), so I'm wondering if there is a specific purpose to how the ".message" suffix is used / not used in message.properties?

Comment: There seem to be quite a bit of mismatches in the messages here, beyond just the use of ".message". For example, the default match failure is "default.doesnt.match.message", the specific error is, for example, "user.login.matches.invalid".  The correct ones to use are in the Constraints quick reference list, http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/matches.html.   I believe the best solution that can be done is to provide a comment at the top of the message.properties file, guiding the user to look at the right place for defining the custom error messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seem to be quite a bit of mismatches in the use of message customization, beyond just the use of ".message". See example below*.

I believe the grails software developers might include a comment at the top of the message.properties file, guiding the user to look at the right place for defining the custom error messages, e.g. in the Constraints quick reference list, http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/matches.html.  The top level Contraints section in the quick reference does not include the error code field names, but might it be useful to add there.

*For example, the default match failure is "default.doesnt.match.message", but the specific error is, for example, "user.login.matches.invalid".

Comment: Thank you man. I was looking for what is custom for `doesnt.match`. After having `not.email` to `email.invalid`. So person.email.email.invalid.