# grails message.properties - how to debug

Tags: grails

I have entries added in message.properties to display customized error messages that totally work, e.g.

```
address.street1.blank=Please provide a street address or P.O. Box
```

I have other entries that all the sudden can't be found after the rename of a class, e.g.:

```
billingshipping.creditCardNumber.blank=Please provide a credit card number
```

The previous customized message worked fine before the refactor/rename of the class "Join" to "BillingShipping", when the error property was called:

```
join.creditCardNumber.blank=Please provide a credit card number
```

I did a clean, and I can also rename the above "address" error property to "addr" and resave the message.properties file, and sure enough I get the default grails error, instead of the custom message.  Change it back again to "address", and I get the custom message, indicating that the file is getting used as expected.

How do I debug further in this case, to figure out what's wrong?

Thanks

P.S. Note these error messages are for display on the same form, using the same controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo.

The class is called "BillingShipping" while the key is "billingshipping". 
Note the capitalization of the "s" in shipping.

Comment: Thank you very much, this fixes the problem.  Do you know why the value "BillingShipping" does not work (which I had tried earlier)?  Is this a grails bug, per the grails documentation: "The class name is looked for both with and without a package, with the packaged version taking precedence."   It makes no reference to using a leading lowercase character for a capitalized class name.

Comment: i can only guess here but i would assume that there is a convention to always start the key with a lowercase letter. If you check the docs for the validator you'll see this: "The class name is looked for both with and without a package, with the packaged version taking precedence. So for example, com.mycompany.myapp.User.login.blank will be used before user.login.blank. This allows for cases where you domain class encounters message code clashes with plugins." So if you specify the full package name the classname is suddenly in the usual form ...

Comment: I see Eike, thanks for pointing this out -- the packaged case / casing.  I've found various issues (seeming bugs) with these property files (e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419036/grails-i18n-error-customization-various-inconsistencies), so I'll have to write up a formal bug.  Thanks again.